# How to start project on react native

Tags: react-native

I installed everything on my computer and also set all environment variables of path and android_home but I still got these errors please help me to solve my problem. My Android studio is also running and the emulator is running too but I don't get what's the problem while running my React native app.

```
C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
```

info Running justifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jenifer found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date
C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 Error:
Attribute application@name value=(com.example.app) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 value=(com.awesomeproject.MainApplication).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android: name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-14:43 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(com.example.app) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38
> is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 value=(com.awesomeproject.MainApplication).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android: name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-14:43 to override.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 Error:
Attribute application@name value=(com.example.app) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 value=(com.awesomeproject.MainApplication).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-14:43 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(com.example.app) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38
> is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-38 value=(com.awesomeproject.MainApplication).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android: name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-14:43 to override.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:610:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:628:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at build and run (C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

Comment: You named you react-native project ""new"" ... and this is not a valid name for javapackage name (cause it is a keyword)... choose a diffent name

Comment: You tried to rename your project package-name ... but I guess in not all locations ... I suggest you create a brand-new-project with a valid-name `react-native init playApp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should rename your react native app and the project package by using this library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

```
npm install react-native-rename

react-native-rename "Travel App" -b com.junedomingo.travelapp
```

Answer (score 1):

You named your react-native project **new** ... and this is not a valid name for *java-package* (cause it is a keyword)...

Answer (score 0):

The very last line of the error message shows

```
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\new\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

You cannot have a keyword in your path name for the project so names like

```
com.new.project
com.class.sample
```

etc are not allowed

change your name to something which is not reserved

like `C:\Users\Pandat\Desktop\React\sample`

Comment: furthermore, it is advised to have the project on a place where you have sufficient read and write permission.

Comment: what is the new project path? is the error same? if yes try putting the project on a separate drive.

Comment: another line in the post suggest gradle 6 issue, try https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/640

Comment: did you try https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/640

Answer (score 0):

use `react-native run-android` instead of `npx react-native run-android` it works for me . hope it too will work for you. Fell free to ask for Doubts.